# How to compare dict with a list in python

Tags: python

Let's say we have these `dict` and `list`:

```
dict = {"a": 20, "b": 3, "c": 50}
list = ["a", "z", "d", "c"]
```

I need a way to get the output below like so: the values of the keys in the dict are summed only if the keys are in the list:

```
70
a c
```

What is the way of doing that? I think in an `if` or `else` comparison but my knowledge extends to here.

Comment: Hello Agat, please  check out the [tour] and the [help], and welcome to Stack Overflow! I noticed your questions has downvote(s) on it, please don't take it personally, it just means somebody thought your question wasn't a good question, not that they don't like you personally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and easy to understand alternative:

```
dict = {"a": 20, "b": 3, "c": 50}
# this creates your dictionary
list = ["a", "z", "d", "c"]
# this creates your list
finalAnswerNumber = 0
# this variable will become "70" in your example
finalAnswerKeys = ""
# This variable is what would output "a" and "c" in your example
for stuff in list:
    # This for statement creates a "stuff" for every element of the list
    if stuff in dict:
        # This if statement checks if "stuff" is a key in dict
        finalAnswerNumber+=dict[stuff]
        # This adds the value for the key "stuff" to the variable finalAnswerNumver, it breaks is the value is a not a number
        finalAnswerKeys+=stuff+" "
        # This adds the "stuff" and a space to the variable finalAnswerKeys
print(finalAnswerNumber)
# The following print functions aren't necessary if you would prefer not to print the values
# this prints the number (in this case 70)
print(finalAnswerKeys)
# this posts the keys (in this case "a" and "c")
```

The output after running this code should look like

```
70
a c
```

Answer (score 3):

Find the union between your list `l` and the keys of your dict `d`. The output is `{a, c}` (<- this is a set). With a list comprehension, get values of your index before to sum:

```
>>> sum(d[i] for i in set(d.keys()).intersection(l))
70
```

Comment: wasn't it also supposed to output "a" and "c"? (or did I misunderstand the question)

Answer (score 3):

Alternative:

```
d = {"a": 20, "b": 3, "c": 50}
l = ["a", "z", "d", "c"]

val_sum = sum(v for k,v in d.items() if k in l) # 70 
keys = ' '.join(k for k,v in d.items() if k in l) # 'a c'
```